# contrib & non-free apt sources gone from jammy?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, updates

I used to add `contrib` & `non-free` to my apt sources, but found they're gone from jammy:

```
$ sudo apt update
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'contrib/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'contrib' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'non-free/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'non-free' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'contrib/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'contrib' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'non-free/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'non-free' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

Then, how to fix common problems like:

```
E: Package 'rar' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'unrar' has no installation candidate
```

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main contrib non-free restricted universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main contrib non-free restricted universe

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

Comment: Neither `contrib` nor `non-free` are pockets in Ubuntu, those are Debian-based pockets.  You want to enable Universe and Multiverse to get those components.

Comment: I suggest you scan https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu  where you'll note no changes have been made since 2017 in fact, ie. prior to Ubuntu 17.10.  I'm very familiar with *contrib* and *non-free* being a Debian user myself, but I've never seen them in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rar` and `unrar` packages are available from the `multiverse` repository. It is enabled by default if it is a regular Ubuntu release.

`contrib` and `non-free` are not Ubuntu repositories, but Debian.